# Why do these videos not work with Firefox anymore?

Tags: firefox, browser, streaming

This is a pretty simple question, and I'm sorry for the little (or no) details I can provide regarding this question, but I'm curious and have no idea how to answer this question of mine. If it belongs elsewhere, also, please don't hesitate to migrate my question.

I watch videos on this streaming website: http://tou.tv

(If you want to check/test, here is a link to a random video from it. I made sure to choose one that's not exclusive to Canada.)

http://www.tou.tv/acoustic/S2009E04

I want to say that I haven't change anything, really, to my computer before the problem arose. There might have been a Firefox update, though I don't remember/didn't notice.

So, here's the problem: Before, the videos worked fine, but since last week, they don't. They display a black rectangle, and nothing happens. No Play button or anything. Page loading finished. I thought there was a problem with the website, because honestly, technically that service sucks in many ways.

But after several days and the problem intact, I thought the issue might be on my side. So I tried it with Chrome. For some reason, the website's template is all off in Chrome, but the video itself works quite fine.

So I would like it if someone could tell me what the problem is in this situation. Is it the Flash player in Firefox? Firefox itself? The website, which updated its "behind" system in a way that forgets to support Firefox?

Comment: It works fine on my machine (with firefox). You should try to update adobe flash player, or if you don't have some addon preventing the video to start. You should also clear your cache, and maybe remove the cookies from the site.

Comment: If it helps any, my version is 20.0 and my OS is Windows 8 Pro.

Comment: Oh, I forgot! Shockwave Flash (it's still called Shockwave? I thought it was Adobe Flash) plugin version, 11.6.602.180 (lol, this complicated version number looks like an IP address.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thank those who have given possible solutions, but a few days later, Firefox update 20.0.1 came and everything was fixed immediately. It was most probably a little bug Firefox had with some specific cases of Flash videos.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly a plugin udate bug. Please do the following.

1. Go to [Plugin Check](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/plugincheck/)
2. Check whether all the plugins are updated or not .
3. Finally make sure plugins like no-script , adblock , flash block are allowing this site to show the flash content.

Comment: Indeed, it wasn't up to date, so I updated it. But it didn't change anything. Also, I want to say that I don't have any plugin that blocks anything, except popups, and it always tells me when it blocks a popup, and it hasn't blocked any from that website.